# frontend backend class exchange

Tags: php, angular, oop

I'm writing application using Angular2 and PHP (REST API mostly). The problem is that I have almost the same classes for angular and for php. For example in php I have a class Contract with some fields like title, description, provider. Also I have api endpoint getContract() to return all these fields. And I have the same class in angular, so I can add some logic here like getters and setters. That's really annoying me to write 2 similar classes each time, and if I need to change something, I have to change it twice. But now I have a new requirement, to create separated project with API, so in two words now I have to create 3 classes each time.

So, if the problem is clear, I want to talk about possible solutions, after google some time I didn't find anything, for now I'm on the first step and hope someone can turn me in the right direction. What's the best practices there? May be store classes in json, and then parse in with angular and php? Thanks for any advices

Comment: best solution is switching to nodejs, so you can keep the same classes on the frontend and the backend for simple data objects. storing classes in JSON sounds like a horrible solution ending in long and painful debugging time. Anyway, you won't be able to share your code between PHP and JS. Also note that even with the same language, developing for different platforms (browser+angular vs nodejs+express or whatever) can be a huge headhache, I hope you are mastering the decorator pattern :D.

Comment: thanks, I like this solution, but unfortunately our company doesn't have resources to move all backend to nodejs. Any other solutions? For now I have only one idea, write integration tests to be sure that my backend/frontend parts are consistency

Comment: also can u explain please what's so wrong with JSON solutions?

Comment: @VictorBredihin Nothing's wrong with JSON solutions inherently. He's a nodejs dogmatist. Or evangelist. Or whatever... he's only got one solution in mind, and everything else is crap to him. But, what's *actually* wrong is spending 100's of hours to save 5 minutes ... regardless of whether that solution is JSON.

Comment: so, do u think I should write 3 classes each time + integration tests?

Comment: "He's a nodejs dogmatist", not at all, I just state that JS platforms are very good at parsing/executing JS. What is wrong with JSON is you will describe your class structure with JSON files, allright, how will you store your classes method ? in plain string, using them with some `eval` ? how will you debug that ? It will be hard to get typeHinting from such dynamic classes, you'll end up writing a class parser for php and JS, that sounds a hard task.

Comment: @VictorBredihin **Probably, but not necessarily.** But, I'll post a longer answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Some repetitive feeling code *isn't repetition in the [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) sense.*

In other words, if you have to spend 10 extra minutes on each model, duplicating fields from one class with one responsibility to another class, potentially in a different language, with *another responsibility*, that's pretty standard. It's OK. And, **it is not vain repetition.**

Your front-end classes and your backend classes might be damn-near identical; but, **they do different things.** The fact that they share fields is *almost* coincidental, and it's not guaranteed. In some applications, the client and server models can diverge quite a bit.

And, it's worth noting, in *many* frameworks, the repetition is even worse than you think! If you separate your server model in a domain and DTO's, you could easily have 2 to 4 "pretty darn identical" server models. And, some MVC client framework result in similar duplicative code. (Or, didn't you realize your templates are yet *another* enumeration of the models in a drastically different syntax?)

... In the end, a really robust application might end up having 4 to 6 *or more* translations of your underlying models.

#### Automatic model/code generation isn't free.

Suppose *all* of your corresponding front-end and back-end classes are *basically* "identical." It will certainly *feel* silly spending 5 minutes copying fields from one syntax to another, but your colleagues will think you're a whole lot sillier if you end up spending a month banging out a solution to save an hour per project.

You'll also feel pretty frustrated when your solution breaks and you end up spending an additional hour or two "every now and then" when the code generator does unexpected things.

Even if you find an off-the-shelf solution that you *only* have install, there's time invested in that. There's a learning curve. There will be maintenance. A there will be unexpected issues.

You *might* save time in the long *long* run; but, you need to do that math

#### That said, there are options.

- You could find a transpiler. Like [this one](http://endel.me/js2php/), or [this one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/php-transpiler), or [this one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/php-transpiler), [etc.](https://www.google.com/search?q=php+javascript+transpiler&oq=php+javascript+transpiler&aqs=chrome..69i57j0j69i64j69i60j69i61.2923j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) ...
- You could load the base models in your JS/PHP from JSON, XML, or *any format you like* and append your logic.
- You could generate your base JS/PHP from JSON, XML, or *any format you like.*
- You could generate your base client models on the fly. I.e., just use the server response as your base model and *append client methods to it.*
- You could generate your base server models on the fly. I.e., your server acts like dumb storage *when possible*. Maybe it knows about *who owns what* ... but not much more. (Just make sure the server models are "smart" for objects passed between users.)
- You could make a case for switching to nodejs!

And maybe you'll sleep better at night spending extra time to avoid repetition of any kind. Maybe you'll feel like your test suite doesn't need to be as big. Or whatever.

If that's the case, go for it.

But, the repetition you're referring to isn't necessarily in vain or abnormal. The client models and the server models should be doing different things, even if they look and feel like vain restatements of each other.

Answer (score 1):

I mean this with complete respect - if you have a problem with writing two different classes, one for Angular and one for your backend, then you shouldn't be using Angular.

Angular is a single page **application** framework. It's a different technique of building a web application whereby you build your user interface as a standalone application in Javascript/Typescript. This application then communicates with a separate server side application through HTTP (or web sockets in some cases).

Therefore, almost by definition, you are going to have two applications. Some people (myself included) combine those applications in a myriad of ways to ease deployment/source code management, but that's just for convenience and with the full understanding that the two applications are still separate entities.

If the idea of having to create similarly named classes for your front end and back end application is too much of a pain, then honestly, I would stick to a normal web application where the user interface is served directly from the server application, and just use javascript to enhance the user interface as needed. *(And that use-case is a very poor fit for Angular - AngularJS i.e. Angular 1, maybe, but definitely not Angular version 2 and beyond)*